# About different method to computer $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\delta_{a}+\delta_{-a}-2\delta}{a^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, distribution-theory

I need see another way to evaluate this limits without using L'Hôpital's rule (H-L). Problem:

> Determine the folowing limit:
>
> $$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\frac{\delta_{a}+\delta_{-a}-2\delta}{a^{2}}$$
>
> where $\delta_{a} $ is the Dirac  distribution at the point $a$.

Answer is $\delta''$. My try using definition:

Let

$$I_{a}=\frac{\delta_{a}+\delta_{-a}-2\delta}{a^{2}}$$

Then:

$$\langle I_{a},\varphi \rangle =\langle \delta , \frac{\varphi (a)+\varphi (-a)-2\varphi (0)}{a^{2}} \rangle$$
Now lim of $I_{a}$

$$\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \langle I_{a},\varphi \rangle = \langle \delta ,\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \frac{\varphi (a)+\varphi (-a)-2\varphi (0)}{a^{2}} \rangle$$ because distribution continuous; now we find:

$$\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \frac{\varphi (a)+\varphi (-a)-2\varphi (0)}{a^{2}} =\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\frac{\varphi '(a)+\varphi ' (-a)}{2a}= \lim\limits_{a\to 0}  
\frac{\varphi ''(a)+\varphi '' (-a)}{2} =\varphi ''(0)$$

then the result.

If you know a simple method, share in this company. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So this seems mostly fine except I think your expression for the very last part of your equality and $\langle I_a, \varphi\rangle$ should really just be

$$ \frac{\varphi(a) + \varphi(-a) - 2\varphi(0)}{a^2}. $$

You've already taken care of the $\delta$ by definition, no need to keep it around. Then

$$\lim_{a\to 0} \langle I_a, \varphi\rangle = \varphi''(0)$$

and so you can associate $\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\delta_a + \delta_{-a} - 2\delta_0}{a^2}$ with $\delta''$ with usual distribution theory duality arguments. It is mistaken to write

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\varphi'(a) - \varphi'(-a)}{2a} = \delta''.$$

(I think you have a sign error.) This is actually equal to $\varphi''(0)$ (per the above) which then allows you to connect back to $\delta''$—but these are not the same thing. One is a compactly supported smooth function; the other is a tempered distribution.

Comment: thanks yes it's mistake typo but how we can use just known limits?

Comment: How do you mean? Do you mean you want another, totally separate proof from what you've presented above?